# Third Party Cookie Expiry Date

Tags: javascript, next.js, cookies, next.js13, third-party-cookies

I am trying to programmatically retrieve the expiry date of a third-party cookie using JavaScript. While I can view the expiry time in the browser's DevTools (see screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/BW072.png, I'm unable to figure out how to obtain this information through code.

I've attempted to use "document.cookie", but it only returns the value of the third-party cookie, not the expiry date. Is there a way to fetch the expiry date using JavaScript?

I would greatly appreciate any insights or code snippets that could help me achieve this. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

```
fetch('https://example.com') // Replace with the URL where the third-party cookie is set
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response.headers.get('Set-Cookie'));
    // Parse the Set-Cookie header to extract expiry date information
    // Remember, not all servers provide this information in the header
  })
  .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).